# The best way to redefine a method in jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let's suppose I want to change the render function in bootstrap-typeahead library.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js

One way to active this goal is to make:

```
_.extend($.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype, {
    render: function (items) {
      // some code
    }
});
```

Let's suppose I want to redefine the render function just for a specific element like…

```
element.typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    source: getSource
});
```

How should I redefine the render function in order to be valid just for this element?

P.S.:
I am using jquery and underscore

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can clone it first?

```
$.fn.typeaheadCustom = $.fn.typeahead;

_.extend($.fn.typeaheadCustom.Constructor.prototype, {
    render: function (items) {
      // some code
    }
 });

element.typeaheadCustom({
    minLength: 3,
    source: getSource
});
```

**UPDATE**

You might need to deep clone it:

```
$.fn.typeaheadCustom = $.extend(true, $.fn.typeahead, {});
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work because `$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render` is changed

Comment: Maybe you need to deep clone it `$.fn.typeaheadCustom = $.extend(true, $.fn.typeahead, {});`

Comment: Also making `$.extend(true, $.fn.typeahead, {});` it does not work.